# Question about trivialisations of a subbundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $p:E\rightarrow M$ be a smooth $r+s$ dimensional vector bundle and $p|_{E'}:E'\rightarrow M$ be a smooth $r$ dimensional subbundle of $E$.

How to show that there exist a system of trivialisation of $E$ such that $h_i(p|_{E'}^{-1}(U_i))=U_i×{\mathbb C}^r×{{0}}^s$ ?

I uderstand that we can do it on a point, because $p|_{E'}^{-1}(x)$ is a $r$ dimensional subspace of $p^{-1}(x)$, but not how we can do it smoothly on the whole $U_i$.

My quetion come from reading [http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~azinger/mat566-spr18/vectorbundles.pdf](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eazinger/mat566-spr18/vectorbundles.pdf) at page 10 on the quotient bundle, the author use the existence of such trivialisations.

The way I understand it is exactly like in an answer of this question:

[Smooth quotient bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059300/smooth-quotient-bundle)

"You have to construct compatible trivializations of the bundles $E'$ and $E$, which is slightly complicated to express in terms of transition functions. The easilest way to describe this in my opinion is in terms of local frames. Choose a local frame for $E'$ defined on $U$. Shrinking $U$, you can extend this to a local frame for $E$. (In a point $x\in U$, extend the values of your frame which form a basis for $E'_x$ to a basis for $E_x$ and then extend the additional elements to local smooth sections of $E$.) Then you get a local trivialization $E|_U\to U\times\mathbb R^n$ which restricts to a trivialzation $E'|_U\to U\times\mathbb R^k$. From this, you get a trivialization from the quotient bundle to $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb R^k\cong\mathbb R^{n-k}$.

In terms of transition functions, you can use the above construction to show that you can arrange things in such a way that the transtition functions for $E$ have values in block matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C\end{pmatrix}$ such that the $A$-component gives you transition functions for $E'$. In this setting, the $C$-block gives you the transition functions for $E/E'$."

But I still dont understand how to "and then extend the additional elements to local smooth sections of $E$".

Comment: What’s your definition of a sub bundle?

Comment: $E'$ is a submanifold of $E$ and  $p|_{E'}:E'\rightarrow M$ is itself a vector bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in M$, pick a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $E'$ is trivial, or equivalently we can find sections $a_1, \cdots, a_r$ of $E'$ that are linearly independent everywhere over $U$.

Now we first extend $a_1(x), \cdots, a_r(x)$ into a basis of $p^{-1}(x)$ by adding $a_{r+1}(x), \cdots, a_{r+s}(x)$. Each $a_i(x)$ for $i>r$ can be extended into a section $a_i$ over an open subset $U_i$ that contains $x$. By taking the intersection of $U_{r+1}, \cdots, U_{r+s}$ and $U$, we may assume all of $a_1, \cdots, a_r, \cdots, a_{r+s}$ are defined over $U$, and they are linearly independent at $x$.

Since being linearly independent is an open condition, we can find open neighborhood $U'\subset U$ of $x$, such that $a_1|_{U'}, \cdots, a_{r+s}|_{U'}$ are linearly independent everywhere over $U'$. Now they can be used to trivilize the whole bundle $E|_{U'}$, such that the subbundle $E'|_{U'}$ is given by exactly those whose last $s$ components are $0$.

Comment: Thank you, but how can you extend the $s$ last $a_i$ since you know only one value, on $x$, for each one ?

Comment: Pick a local trivilization $V$ of $E$, say $a_i$ at $x$ have coordinates $(c_1, \cdots, c_{r+s})$. Then we may just use the same coordinates everywhere on $V$. That is, the section is just $y\mapsto (y, c_1, \cdots, c_{r+s})$ under the trivilization (an isomorphism from $E|_V$ to $V\times\mathbb C^{r+s}$)

Comment: Okay, and then the result follow from "being linearly independent is an open condition", that we can deduce by the non-vanishing of a determinant. Thank you.